# Create a .txt list of IPs in a subnet

Tags: python

I'd like to make a very simple text (.txt) file.  This python program needs to make a list of multiple ranges of IPs in a subnet, each taking up one line.

Example:

```
10.10.27.1
10.10.27.5
10.10.27.6
10.10.27.26
10.10.27.27
10.10.27.28
10.10.27.29
10.10.27.51
10.10.27.52
10.10.27.53
10.10.27.54
```

The subnet mask will essentially always be a /24, so providing mask input is not necessary.  The program can even default to only supporting a standard class C.

Also, I'd like to support common ranges for devices that we use.  A prompt for say, "Printers?" will include .26 - .30.  "Servers?" will include .5 - .7.  "DHCP?" prompt always will include .51 - .100 of the subnet. "Abnormal?" will include .100 - .254.

```
Subnet?  10.10.27.1
Servers?  Y
Printers?  Y
DHCP?  Y
Abnormal?  N
```

Output being:

```
10.10.27.1
10.10.27.5
10.10.27.6
10.10.27.7
10.10.27.26
10.10.27.27
10.10.27.28
10.10.27.29
10.10.27.30
10.10.27.51 (all the way to .100)
```

What is the best way to code this?

Comment: how did `10.10.27.7` and `*.30` get into the output? And what's the difference between input and output otherwise?

Comment: I think is much better to do a simple shell script with nmap.

Comment: Is this just generating a list of values?  What `for` loop have you tried?

Comment: .5, .6, and .7 got there because the user said 'Y' to servers. I think the OP is saying that once the 'Subnet' is input, the class C is assumed thereafter. So 10.10.27 is the prefix. Saying 'Y' to servers now mean that 10.10.27.5 through .7 will be used. and so on.

Comment: As Greg said, thank you.


Simple shell script with nmap?  I am familiar with nmap, and use it often.  The purpose of this text file will be to help with creating IP lists on the fly for a constant ping program on Windows to read.  Otherwise, I'd utilize that.

@ S.lott - Yes, generating this list as described.  I haven't tried anything yet, I wanted to get some advice first.  I am new to writing code from scratch, yet not to modifying code.  I'd like to better understand how to do this best from the start.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a few `for` loops are all you need:

```
network = '10.10.27'

for host in xrange(100, 255):
   print("{network}.{host}".format(**locals()))
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could claim original credit, but I first saw it somewhere else on SO. Sure beats making your own dict (though I've never done speed tests to compare)

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the script simple, just output all addresses as needed :)

```
def yesno(question):
    output = input(question).lower()

    if output == 'y':
        return True
    elif output == 'n':
        return False
    else:
        print '%r is not a valid response, only "y" and "n" are allowed.' % output
        return yesno(question)

addresses = []

subnet = input('Subnet? ')
# Remove the last digit and replace it with a %d for formatting later
subnet, address = subnet.rsplit('.', 1)
subnet += '%d'
addresses.append(int(address))

if yesno('Servers? '):
    addresses += range(5, 8)

if yesno('Printers? '):
    addresses += range(26, 31)

if yesno('DHCP? '):
    addresses += range(51, 101)

if yesno('Abnormal? '):
    addresses += range(100, 255)

for address in addresses:
    print subnet % address
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick little script I threw together...

```
import socket
import sys


ranges = {'servers':(5, 8), 'printers':(26, 31), 'dhcp':(51, 101), 'abnormal':(101, 256)}

subnet = raw_input("Subnet? ")

try:
    socket.inet_aton(subnet)
except socket.error:
    print "Not a valid subnet"
    sys.exit(1)

ip_parts = subnet.split(".")
if len(ip_parts) < 3:
    print "Need at least three octets"
    sys.exit(1)
ip_parts = ip_parts[:3]
ip = ".".join(ip_parts)

include_groups = []
last_octets = []

servers = raw_input("Servers? ")
printers = raw_input("Printers? ")
dhcp = raw_input("DHCP? ")
abnormal = raw_input("Abnormal? ")

if servers == "Y":
    include_groups.append('servers')
if printers == "Y":
    include_groups.append('printers')
if dhcp == "Y":
    include_groups.append('dhcp')
if abnormal == "Y":
    include_groups.append('abnormal')

for group in include_groups:
    last_octets.extend([x for x in xrange(ranges[group][0], ranges[group][1])])

print "%s.1" %(ip)
for octet in last_octets:
    print "%s.%s" %(ip, octet)
```

Comment: Thanks guys!  I am going to try both of these out and see what works best.  I will throw together / modify as I see fit, and post back.  

You've been a great help.